# Regex to check time period value 1W, 5Y

Tags: c#, regex, validation

Here I need to validate a string like this in **C#**:

The string's max length: 4

The last character should be any one from D, W, M, Y (representing day,week,month,year)

The rest(initial) all characters should be a non negative number.

Example:

Valid values : "1D", "4w", "26W", "3M","24M","5Y" etc

Invalid values : "M3","360DM","5555D", "1Y2M", "-5Y" etc

Comment: "I need to" is not a question. What have you tried? Where exactly do you have problems?

Comment: Hi @KlausGütter, It's difficult for me to understand the regex norms. Also if you browse any regex answers here and anywhere - even the experts would answer by "I would go for this" kind of answers - so they are also not sure if it works on all platform. That's why asking for help here by specifying my exact requirement. Would it be ok if I say "I want to" instead of "I need to" ?

Comment: no, even THAT is not okay. Why don't you try to read the regex documentation on msdn? THIS is the baseline on all plattforms when you come with c#. Every pattern will have the same result. And yes. Regex is pretty tough to understand, but we are here to HELP, not to do "your" work so, try something. and come back with a more specific question like "i tried this pattern, but can't get just X, i always catch invalid matches" or something

Comment: True and noted. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Arjun, SO has a rule that if a question is a homework problem the asker is expected to explain what efforts they have made to answer the question themselves. That does not necessarily require the presentation of code. (I personally believe it is demeaning to force askers, newbies especially, to produce code--which they may know to be terrible--in order for them to get help here.) If it is not a homework question, and I have no reason to believe this is one, there is no SO rule that you must produce code that you have tried.

Comment: Yes, Cary it was an urgent requirement to fulfill in short time and also I did not want to put in place clumsy string operations coding. So with less knowledge of regex, 
 required to speak out to the community in a hurry. :-) Regds.

Comment: Arjun, just a reminder that when you leave a comment directed at a member (other than the author of a question or answer) you need to include the member's username (e.g., @ZaphodBeeblebrox) for them to be informed by SO that a comment has been left for them. (I just happened to notice your reply to my comment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following regular expression (with the case-indifferent flag set).

```
^(?:0|[1-9]\d{0,2})[DWMY]$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9waqQO/1/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^           match the beginning of the string
(?:         begin a non-capture group
  0         match '0'
  |         or
  [1-9]     match a digit other than '0'
  \d{0,2}   match 0-2 digits
)           end non-capture group
[DWMY]      match one of the characters indicated
$           match end of string
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked. I was just struggling to refine the previous hint answer, but none of my adjustments were working.

Answer (score 0):

Bad Question, nontheless that's quite basic for a regex: `string pattern = "([0-9]{1-3})([YDWM])";` it's up to you to refine this pattern for case sensitivity. you have multiple choices on how to handle that

Comment: The requirements do not say that the number is optional, so maybe the `?` should be removed.

Comment: you're right! For the sake of correctness i will fix that :)

Comment: This matches "my dog has0000000DEFleas". You don't need capture groups for verification. If you believe it is a "bad question", please explain why, preferably in a comment on the question.